# Basic Java Float and Integer multiplication casting

Tags: java, math

I have the following code:

```
float f = 1.5f;
int i = 3;
i *= f;
```

I receive no warning, but if I do

```
i = i*f
```

I receive an incompatible type warning.  Why does Java automatically cast the first multiplication but not the second? What is the reasoning behind this?

Comment: Good answer, couldn't find it originally though because of poor keyword searches. Thanks :)

Comment: Just for all the people that are as curios as I was: This will fail in C# for both assignments with the following error: `Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`